# how to move an object to another with java script using css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, jquery-animate

i am trying to create a coin collection animation  to the cart using java script/ Vue js only. so i decided to do it with raw java script. so initally i was trying watching w3schools this tutorial
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_animate_3

somewhere i have a destination div which is the cart below

```
<div class="coin"  id="coin" @click="collect()">
```

and somewhere i have the the div which is to be animated and runs towards the div id "coin"

```
<div id ="animate">
</div>
```

here is my css

```
.coin {
  background-image: 
  url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/ce/a6/15cea65c1fadcfcb144f3b41e32bd9b3.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

#animate {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: red;
  }
```

and this is my javascript function below

```
collect(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
      function frame() {
         if (pos == 350) {
         clearInterval(id);
     } else {
          pos++; 
          var testDiv = document.getElementById("coin");
          elem.style.top = testDiv.offsetTop; 
          elem.style.left = testDiv.offsetLeft; 
      }
    }
        }
```

here i was trying to follow the destination div's left right property where the animation didnt work ..please help me to reach the div to destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to define a units. add `px` to the given `top` and `left`
2. You should use `getClientBoundingRect` instead of `offset`, since `offset` return the offset of the element from its parent, and not from the page. so if the two elements not share the same parent - use `getClientBoundingRect`
3. For now you trying to move the element to the final position from the very first step.. if you trying to animate it in 350 steps (as it's look like in your code) you should move the element just 1/350 from the required path at any step.

Finally, it's should look like somehow like this: (I would reccomend to reduce the number of steps):

```js
function collect(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("animate");  
    var testDiv = document.getElementById("coin");
    var diffX = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left - elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var diffY = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top - elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var dx = diffX / 350;
    var dy = diffY / 350;
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
         if (pos == 350) {
         clearInterval(id);
     } else {
          pos++; 
          elem.style.top = (parseFloat(elem.style.top)||0) + dy + 'px'; 
          elem.style.left = (parseFloat(elem.style.left)||0) + dx + 'px'; 
      }
    }

}
```

```css
.coin {
  background-image: 
  url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/ce/a6/15cea65c1fadcfcb144f3b41e32bd9b3.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

#animate {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="coin"  id="coin" onclick="collect()"></div>
<div id ="animate"></div>
```

As for me, I more like to use `requestAnimationFrame` with a recursive function. like this:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");  
var testDiv = document.getElementById("coin");
var rate = 1/75;
var diffX, diffY;
function collect() {
    diffX = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left - elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    diffY = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top - elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    frame();
}
function frame() {
  if(Math.abs(testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left - elem.getBoundingClientRect().left) < diffX*rate) return;
  elem.style.top = (parseFloat(elem.style.top)||0) + diffY*rate + 'px'; 
  elem.style.left = (parseFloat(elem.style.left)||0) + diffX*rate + 'px'; 
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
```

```css
.coin {
  background-image: 
  url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/ce/a6/15cea65c1fadcfcb144f3b41e32bd9b3.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

#animate {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="coin"  id="coin" onclick="collect()"></div>
<div id ="animate"></div>
```

Comment: thanks Yosef..I  gave the pos as 350 as testing as it was given in w3school. can you show me a way as wherever i place the div which is to be moved will follow its destination automatically.??

Comment: The examples above should work in wherever you placing the div. did you got any problems with it?

Comment: i did try your first example..are u talking about the last one.?

Comment: both. What problem did you got?